# Use SQL to select one id that correspond to two indexing words in two rows

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm trying to select the ids that have indices "a" and "b" by joining 3 tables, then using WHERE to select the rows I need. The three tables have roughly the following schema:

```
Table 1: id | name | description
Table 2: id | start_time | date
Table 3: id | word
```

I joined the 3 tables on id. Table 3 has a one-to-many relationship, where 1 id corresponds to multiple words:

```
id | word
 1 | apple
 1 | bee
 2 | abandon
 2 | apple
 2 | bee
```

After joining the tables, they would look like

```
id | name | description | start_time | date | word
 1 | 100  | abcd        | 1200       | M    | apple
 1 | 100  | abcd        | 1200       | M    | bee
 2 | 200  | efgh        | 2200       | T    | abandon
 ...
```

My goal would be to select the ids that correspond to both the word "apple" and "bee", as well as having a specific start time and date. But I can't use

```
SELECT id 
FROM table 
WHERE start_time = 1200 
  AND date = "M" 
  AND word = "apple" AND word = "bee"
```

Because a single row can't hold both "apple" and "bee". Can someone explain how to select the ids that correspond to words in two different rows? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answers the original version of the question.

Use aggregation and `having`:

```
SELECT id
FROM table
WHERE word IN ('apple', 'bee')
GROUP BY id
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2;
```

Note:  This assumes that you have no duplicates.  If you can have duplicates, use `COUNT(DISTINCT word) = 2`.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=66cef69096ce92f27b356299e8bfa2ce) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: @numkinpie . . . I added a db<>fiddle illustrating that it works.

Comment: I edited the question to include a fuller picture. I omitted the other complications because I thought they would be irrelevant, but maybe they are not.

Comment: Modified this and solved the problem, thank you!